# Can vim highlight current matching words when I input replace command?

Tags: vim

Can vim(or by some plugin) highlight current matching words when I input replace command? For example, given following document:

```
attribute_list = [
    ("attribute_1", int),
    ("attribute_2", float),
    ("attribute_3", int),
]
```

I want to replace all `int` by `bool` with vim command `:%s/int/bool/g`. When I input `:%s/in` can vim highlight all the `in` in the document? I need this feature because I want to check my search pattern is correct when I replace some text by regexp.

The vim plugin [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) have a similar feature. It can highlight all the current matching words when you search.

Comment: Assuming you have hlsearch and incsearch set, how about first searching using `/` and after you have verified replacing?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Before I ask this question, I do first searching using `/` before replacing. I ask this question because I don't want to type the search pattern twice. But now I saw the answer of @IngoKarkat, turn out I don't need to repeat the search pattern. So I think it acceptable for me.

Comment: I didn't know you didn't know about not having to repeat the search pattern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such built-in option. Such behavior could be built by hooking into the typing of characters into the command-line, but as there's no generic autocmd for that, you'd have to override every possible typed key, and run the risk of interfering with other plugins or abbreviations.

There's a simple tweak to your workflow that gives you similar behavior, though, and I would suggest that as a much better alternative: First search for the pattern via `/int`; if you have `:set hlsearch incsearch`, you'll then have the on-the-fly highlighting of matches. Accept the match via `<CR>`, and *then* do the subsitution. You don't need to repeat the search pattern there, so this becomes:

```
:%s//bool/g
```

Comment: Didn't know I don't need to repeat the search pattern. Thank you.